# Mock user console input in junit test

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I am trying to mock multiple user inputs via the console, I am having an issue while reading '>1' as an input. Reading just '1' seems to be fine.

Given the following method to be tested:

```
public int getMainMenuSelectedOption() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    while ((i < 1) || (i > 5)) {
      System.out.println("Invalid option, please select again");
      i = scan.nextInt();
    }
    return i;
}
```

I wrote the test as such

```
private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
private final ByteArrayOutputStream errContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

@Before
public void setUpStreams() {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));
}

@Test
public void testGetMainMenuSelectedOptionNotifyInvalidOption() {
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("0".getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);
    app.getMainMenuSelectedOption();
    assertEquals("Invalid option, please select again", outContent.toString());
    ByteArrayInputStream in2 = new ByteArrayInputStream("1".getBytes());
    System.setIn(in2);
}

// Also tried with SequenceInputStream. This will not get the expected outstream of "Invalid option".
@Test
public void testGetMainMenuSelectedOptionNotifyInvalidOption() {
    ByteArrayInputStream in1 = new ByteArrayInputStream("0".getBytes());
    ByteArrayInputStream in2 = new ByteArrayInputStream("1".getBytes());
    SequenceInputStream in = new SequenceInputStream(in1,in2);
    System.setIn(in);
    app.getMainMenuSelectedOption();
    assertEquals("Invalid option, please select again\n", outContent.toString());
}

// This test runs fine
@Test
public void testGetMainMenuSelectedValidOption() {
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("1".getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);
    app.getMainMenuSelectedOption();   
}
```

I got the following error

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at com.twu.biblioteca.BibliotecaApp.getMainMenuSelectedOption(BibliotecaApp.java:42)
    at com.twu.biblioteca.ExampleTest.testGetMainMenuSelectedOptionNotifyInvalidOption(ExampleTest.java:73)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your method:

```
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   int i = scan.nextInt();
   while ((i < 1) || (i > 5)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid option, please select again");
        i = scan.nextInt();
    }
    return i;
```

for input `0` reads the  element `0` to `i`, then enters the loop (because the condition is `i<1`), then prints a message, then is trying to scan next element in the loop. Because input stream is already exhausted
according to [the documentation of Scanner#nextInt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083065/mock-user-console-input-in-junit-test):

> **Throws:**
>   NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted

In my opinion everything is fine (except an error in the logic of your method).

**----------
EDIT
----------**

> The valid inputs should be 1 to 4, both inclusive. Why is the input
>   stream exhausted?

I do not know why you do not use the debugger to check what is happening in your code, just click some line at the right bar in your IDE to set up a breakpoint, then right-click your test method and choose "debug" from the context menu.
Anyway, lets debug your method for input `0` step by step on the paper:

```
1   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
2   int i = scan.nextInt();
3   while ((i < 1) || (i > 5)) {
4        System.out.println("Invalid option, please select again");
5        i = scan.nextInt();
6    }
7    return i;
```

The input buffer contains single character `0`.

- The execution flow moves to line 2
- In line 2 the scanner reads a character `0` from the input stream to variable `i`. The variable `i` now contains `0` value. After this the input stream is empty (is exhasted)
- in line 3 the condition `((i < 1) || (i > 5))` is checked. Since `i` is equal to `0`, the condition is true, and the program flow enters into the loop
- in line 4 the message is printed to the console
- in line 5 the scanner is trying to read a next integer from the input buffer. **Since the input buffer is exhausted, the exception is thrown**

I think it should be clear now. Why is the input stream exhausted? Because it had only one element `0` which had been readed at line 2, then at line 5 it was empty (exhausted)
 Your code has an error - but that's why we have a unit test to find such errors). 
Tip: use [Scannes#hasNextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) method to test whether there is next int in the input stream in order to avoid the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you adopt a new method of handling your test.

Implement your own `ByteArrayInputStream` -> simply extend the existing ByteArrayInputStream into your very own MyTestByteArrayInputStream.

Consider the following example :

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class MyClass {

    public static class MyTestByteArrayInputStream extends ByteArrayInputStream {
        private Byte mockedBuffer = null;

        public MyTestByteArrayInputStream(byte b) {
            super(new byte[] {b});
            this.mockedBuffer = b;
        }

        public MyTestByteArrayInputStream(byte[] in) {
            super(in);
        }
        public MyTestByteArrayInputStream(byte[] in, int offset, int length) {
            super(in,offset,length);
        }

        @Override
        public int read() {
            if(mockedBuffer == null) {
                return super.read();
            }
            else {
                return mockedBuffer;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        byte b = 49;
        MyTestByteArrayInputStream myTestInputStream = new MyTestByteArrayInputStream(b);
        IntStream.range(0,10).forEach(i -> {
                System.out.println("Invoking #" + i +": " + myTestInputStream.read()); 
            });
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Invoking #0: 49
Invoking #1: 49
Invoking #2: 49
Invoking #3: 49
Invoking #4: 49
Invoking #5: 49
Invoking #6: 49
Invoking #7: 49
Invoking #8: 49
Invoking #9: 49
```

You have a lot of versatility with your mocking implementation.

In my example, I added a constructor which allows you to instantiate the IS with a single byte, which will later be the only output of the read() overridden method.

This means you will not have to 'feed' the input stream with inputs - invoking the read() method will never cause an NoSuchElementException.

I would also highly reccoment you use an actual mocking framework : [JMock](http://jmock.org/) and [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) are very well know and usefull tools used extensively in Unit testing.

Using a mocking framework will save you the need to actually implement a MyTestByteArrayInputStream - Instead you will simply override the behaviour of a specific ByteArrayInputStream instance.

Hope this helps and feel free to ask/comment about this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured, to setup sequential console inputstream, just add "\n" as linebreak.

For example, I wanted a '0', followed by '1' console input, so the following will work

```
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("0\n1\n".getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);
    app.getMainMenuSelectedOption();
    assertEquals("Invalid option, please select again\n", outContent.toString());
```